# YoloV5s How to output FPS from inference time

Tags: python, object-detection, frame-rate, yolo, yolov5

New to Yolo and python,
I'm using the PyTorch detect.py script from

https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/detect.py

and I want to output the FPS.

When I run my model I get the inference time of the detection per frame. (I'm assuming).
the output range between 1.5 to 1.7 s

How can I convert the inference time estimate to FPS? or output the FPS using this code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of FPS is `1 / inference_time`, just compute this value. In your case, with an inference time of around 1.5 s, you should obtain around 0.66 fps.